# Allowing access to an MVC site using Windows Authentication Via groups via username

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, roleprovider, active-directory-group

I have an MVC2 site that now allows access to it via windows authentication and uses ASP.net Role provider to provide authorization.  I am trying to come up with a way for the site to allow the user access to the site if his username is a member of certain groups so I won't have to sign up user in sql, but just sign up a group with access.  Anybody have any idea how to do this?  Is there a quick and dirty way?  So far in my internet perusals I haven't found a quick and dirty way to do this?  Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: so you are trying to blend windows and forms auth?

Comment: No.  I have windows authentication and want to keep it that way.  I was just wondering if there was some way to check a users groups, if he is a member of that group, then he has access to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking up Role/Group information for a User

ASP.NET provides a useful “Role Management” capability, which allows developers to map users into logical “Roles” that can then be used to better control end-user capabilities and authorization access.  For example, as a developer I could create a role called “managers” for my web application, and then limit access to portions of the site to only those users within the “managers” role (note: I will be posting additional recipes in the future that discuss how to fully use the Role Management authorization and capabilities features more).

When using Windows Authentication, ASP.NET allows developers to create and populate roles from multiple sources.  For example, a developer could setup the built-in ASP.NET 2.0 SqlRoleProvider to map Windows users to custom application roles that are store within a database.  This approach is very useful for scenarios where there might be application-specific role mappings that don’t make sense to push into a centralized Active Directory tree/store.

ASP.NET also makes it easy to access central Windows and Active Directory group mappings from within an application as well.  For example, if there is a Windows group on the Active Directory network called “DOMAIN\managers”, an ASP.NET application could lookup whether the current Windows authenticated user visiting the ASP.NET site belongs to this group by writing code like this:

```
If User.IsInRole("DOMAIN\managers") Then
     Label1.Text = User.Identity.Name & " is a manager"
Else
     Label1.Text = User.Identity.Name & " is not a manager"
End If
```

Note that the role/group look-up is done via the “User.IsInRole(rolename)” method that is a peer of the User.Identity.Name property.

src
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/12/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application.aspx